# will a person enter jannah if he doesn't obey his parents

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Will a anyone enter if he doesn't listen his parents;
i heard that he won't enter unless he is dutiful, i.e obedient

Comment: It is subject to the will of Allah. We shouldn't assume.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, so I will answer it first.

Respect for the rights of parents is one of the moral teachings of Islam and is emphasized in the Qur'an and hadiths. In the Qur'an, benevolence towards parents is mentioned after worshiping God and forbidding him from associating partners with Him, and thanksgiving to parents is equated with thanksgiving to God; Of course, obedience to parents should not lead to divine opposition.
In the hadiths, obedience to parents is a sign of faith, looking at them, worshiping and treating them with kindness are among the most beloved deeds in the sight of God and divine pleasure and wrath in the pleasure or dissatisfaction of parents with their children. According to the narrations, a person who does good to his parents will enter Paradise, and the good deeds that he does on behalf of his parents, and even more, will be recorded for him. In the face of the curse of the parents, it causes deprivation of paradise, God's curse, deprivation of God's attention, mercy and blessings.

"We have enjoined man to be good to his parents. But if they urge you to ascribe to Me as partner that of which you have no knowledge, then do not obey them. To Me will be your return, whereat I will inform you concerning what you used to do" 29:8
" ...do not say to them, ‘Fie!’ And do not chide them, but speak to them noble words." 17:23
But you may disagree on some issues, such as which company you work for or who you marry, and so on. Quranic teachings ask you to treat them with courtesy, respect and good manners.

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%AD%D9%82_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86